# How do you print out Experience Profile Reports in Sitecore 8?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

The Sitecore 8 Experience Profile dashboard provides a ton of useful information.  However I need to be able to share this information.  Is there a printable version of Experience Profile analytics for a particular user's sessions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no printable version available. Sitecore does not provide such tool out of the box. We have also checked with Sitecore support in the past and they have recommended to print report from the browser or print a screenshot of the report.